# In MS Access, is there an easy way to show $0.00 amounts when the query result is null?

Tags: ms-access, null

In my MS Access report, calculated currency fields show #Type! or #Error! if one of the amounts (e.g., quantity) returned from a query is null because the queried table is empty.  Is there an easy way to display/print $0.00 for these fields?

I have investigated numerous alternatives on this site and other sources, and have tried various combinations of Nz(quantity, 0), IIf(([quantity]) Is Null, 0, ([quantity]*[unit cost])), etc. with no good results.

Comment: You still want report to open if there is no data?

Comment: Direct answer is no. There is no record for any of those functions to work with so they fail - there isn't even a Null field. Do calculation in query. Textboxes should not show error because there is no calculation taking place on report. I have a label "There is no data" display when report does not have data.

Comment: June, thanks.  Yes, I'd still like the report to show up, your suggestions are helpful and I'll look into them.  At first glance, your first one seems most appropriate.  I'll try to figure out how to do as you suggest.  

At least I know to stop my search and trying to fudge the report to display zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct answer to your yes/no question is "No". Only options I know of:

1) don't open report if there is no data

One approach uses OnNoData event

```
Private Sub Report_NoData(Cancel As Integer)
MsgBox "There is no data, report opening is cancelled."
Cancel = True
End Sub
```

However, to deal with error 2501, need error handler in procedure that opens report - review [Access: Canceling Report generation causes error 2501](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492231/access-canceling-report-generation-causes-error-2501)

Alternative is to not even initiate report open if there is no data -  do DCount or DLookup (use same filter criteria applied to report) on table or query object that is report RecordSource and use If Then conditional based on value returned.

2) do calculations in query instead of textboxes on report and have a message on report "No data available" display when there is no data

- VBA in report Detail section OnFormat event to dynamically hide label control, example: `Me.lblND.Visible = Not Me.HasData` (be aware event only triggers for PrintPreview or direct to printer)
- or an expression in textbox: `=IIf([HasData], " ", "No data available")` and no VBA is needed.

3) UNION a dummy record of 0 values - might be able to suppress display of this record if report has data - I've never tried this